# Constructor chaining with array in Java

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out how to chain constructors when the constructor I'm trying to call is supposed to use values passed to the constructor I'm calling it from.

I tried this:

```
public BoundingBox(Point a, Point b)
{
    Point[] points = {a, b}
    this(points); 
}
```

but I'm told that the call to `this` must be on the first line of the constructor.

I'm trying to call this constructor

```
public BoundingBox(Point[] input)
{
    //do some work
}
```

Ideally, I could chain these constructors. Otherwise, I may have to restructure my code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is possible via

```
this(new Point[] {a, b});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can replace the two constructor with the following that uses **Varargs**

```
public BoundingBox(Point ... input){
    //do some work
}
```

Brief about **Varargs**

a method may use a vararg parameter (variable argu-
ment) as if it is an array. It is a little different than an array, though. A vararg parameter
must be the last element in a method’s parameter list. This implies you are only allowed to
have one vararg parameter per method.

When calling a method with a vararg parameter, you have a choice. You can pass in an
array, or you can list the elements of the array and let Java create it for you. You can even
omit the vararg values in the method call and Java will create an array of length zero for
you.

Comment: @malverndongeni usually a better definition is `public BoundingBox(Point first, Point ... rest){`

Comment: @Eugene you are right.but that approach will require us to define no argument constructor as this case will fail `new BoundingBox()`  moreover,It will force us to supply first Point. *NB there is a brief description of how varargs works which is inline with your approach

Comment: The argument for `Point first, Point ... rest` depends on the use case. *If* a no-arg constructor is valid, e.g. you can create a `BoundingBox` without any points then using only one vararg argument is perfectly fine. If on the other hand you always have to have at least one point then you may want to use `first, rest` approach or even `first, second, third, rest` depending how many points are the minimum.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static function that creates the array

```
static private Point[] createPointArray(Point a, Point b) 
{ 
    Point[] points = {a, b}
    return points;
}

public BoundingBox(Point a, Point b)
{
    this(createPointArray(a,b)); 
}
```

Comment: I really like the static factory method approach, come in handy when creating more complicated objects.